# How to call interface particular method in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a one interface. Inside the interface i have 3 method.

```
public interface interfaceMethod
{
   string methodA();
   string methodB();
   string methodC();
}
```

I would like to call only one method for methodA() without referring all interface method. How to call only one method instead of referring all method.

```
Public class Class1
{
   public string testCallInterfaceMethod()
   {
       interfaceMethod obj = new interfaceMethod();
       obj.callMethodA();
   }   
}
```

Comment: You can not instantiate interface, is your code getting compiled?

Comment: As Adil said : you cannot instantiate interface. But you can create a class, which will implement only MethodA and throw exceptions for method and methodC

Comment: I am getting below error.

Comment: There was no endpoint listening at http://gcwvd152e:8020/local/System/System/ProxyFactory that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Comment: Your provided code not enough to explain why you face error. 

Also, you can create a class implement interface, override `methodA`, leave blank body (return null, or sth) on method B, C

Answer (score 4):

Why make an interface/contract and then not adhere to it? Sounds like a perfect use case for two interfaces.

```
public interface interfaceMethod
{
   string methodA();
}

public interface anotherInterface : interfaceMethod
{
   string methodB();
   string methodC();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interface is just a contract. A class can sign that contract and then implement the methods which the contract requires it to. Using your interface, the following code will work:

```
public interface InterfaceMethod
{
   string methodA();
   string methodB();
   string methodC();
}

Public class Class1 : InterfaceMethod
{
   //Implementation of InterfaceMethod interface
   public string MethodA() { /* Code */ }

   public string MethodB() { /* Code */ }

   public string MethodC() { /* Code */ }

   /* Class' other code */
}
```

Somewhere else...

```
public string testCallInterfaceMethod()
{
    InterfaceMethod im = new Class1();
    Console.WriteLine(im.MethodA());
    Console.WriteLine(im.MethodB());
    Console.WriteLine(im.MethodC());
    return null;
}
```